# Transfer Bulk data through WebService

Tags: c#-2.0

I am Using webservice For Desktop application(coded in c#.net),I need to transfer 1,00,000 Records through webservice,but while debugging ,It throws an Exception i.e. The Underlying connection was closed.........I need to check the debugging Process int the application & the webservice,Can any one help me..............Thanks in Advance...........

Comment: Was it the HTTP or database connection that was closed?

Comment: The error "Underlying connection was closed" seems to indicate that maybe your webservice / db connection itself is not open. Can you provide some code / more detailed information as to what point u are getting the error and maybe stack trace of the error itself. This is very ambigiuous.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase your timeouts in both client and server configs, also you may have to increase other values too depending on how big the chunks of data is.

These limits are in place to prevent DOS attacks out of the box.

Comment: I tried the following in webconfig:
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1100" maxRequestLength="5000000" requestLengthDiskThreshold="80" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="5000" enableKernelOutputCache="true"
enableVersionHeader="true" requireRootedSaveAsPath="true" enable="true" shutdownTimeout="900" delayNotificationTimeout="5" waitChangeNotification="0" maxWaitChangeNotification="0"  requestPriority="Normal" enableHeaderChecking="true"
sendCacheControlHeader="true"apartmentThreading="false"/>
Its not working.Pls Suggest.

Comment: @narmadha: Please provide the exact exception you are getting. They normally provide the answer there.